# Application crashes in device while working fine in emulator : NullPointerException

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception

I am developing one socket based application. but the problem is my application working properly in emulator but when i tested in real devices it crashed many times.

Here is my Logcat :

```
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.inextrix.automation/org.inextrix.automation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at org.inextrix.automation.MainActivity$1.updateStatus(MainActivity.java:272)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at org.inextrix.automation.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:250)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at org.inextrix.automation.MainActivity.startRepeatingTask(MainActivity.java:485)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at org.inextrix.automation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:205)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-21 16:24:38.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3525):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);            
    getSharedSettings();

    fanDimmer1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_fan1);
    fanDimmer2=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_fan2);
    dimmerLight1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_light1);
    dimmerLight2=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_light2);


    fanDimmer1.setOnClickListener(this);
    fanDimmer2.setOnClickListener(this);
    dimmerLight1.setOnClickListener(this);
    dimmerLight2.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(ip.equals("") || port.equals(""))
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Warning !")
        .setMessage("Please set IP and PORT first")
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setNeutralButton("ok", null)
        .show();
    }
    else
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "openconnection");
                openConnection();
            }
        }).start();
        m_handler = new Handler();
        startRepeatingTask();

    }

}

public void openConnection()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try 
    {
        s = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
        i = s.getInputStream();
        iD = new DataInputStream(i);
        o = s.getOutputStream();
        oD = new DataOutputStream(o);
        Log.v(TAG, "openconnection 2");

    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.v("UnknowHostException :::::", "In Catch Block");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.v("IOException :::::", "In Catch Block");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        if (count == 0) {
            updateStatus();
            count = 1;
        } else {
            updateStatus1();
            count = 0;
        }
        m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker,1000);
    }

    private void updateStatus() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("test", "1");
        try {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
                { 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06, 
                    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x19
                };

            o.write(packet1); //line number 272
            i.read(data1, 0, 1024);

            byte_to_hex = ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(18, 26);

            /*Log.d(TAG,"Original String ::: "+ byte_to_hex);*/

            char[] arr = byte_to_hex.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) 
            {
                char temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            swapped_result=new String(arr);
            result = ConversionMethods.hexStringToNBitBinary(swapped_result, 32);

            int counter = 0;
            for( int i=0; i<result.length(); i++ ) 
            {
                if( result.charAt(i) == '1' )
                {
                    counter++;        
                }  
            }

            status=Integer.toString(counter);
            txt_status.setText(status);
            Log.v(TAG, "status is ::"+status);


            char[] c=result.toCharArray();
            int count=0;
            for (int i=0;i<result.length();i++)
            {
                count++;
                char j=c[i];
                //Log.v(TAG, count+"::"+j);
                if(count==1)
                    toggleButton=dimmerLight1;
                else if(count==2)
                    toggleButton=fanDimmer2;
                else if(count==3)
                    toggleButton=fanDimmer1;
                else if(count==4)
                    Log.v(TAG, "Count 4 is 0");

                if(j=='1')
                    toggleButton.setChecked(true);
                else
                    toggleButton.setChecked(false); 
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void updateStatus1() 
    {
        Log.v("test", "2");
        try {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
                { 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06, 
                    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x03,(byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x04
                };

            o.write(packet1);
            i.read(data1, 0, 1024);

            /*Log.v("::::TX::::", ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(0, 34));
            Log.v("::::RX::::", ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(packet1));*/

            d1=ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(20, 22);
            d2=ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(24, 26);
            d3=ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(28, 30);
            d4=ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(32, 34);

            Log.v(TAG, "D1="+d1);
            Log.v(TAG, "D2="+d2);
            Log.v(TAG, "D3="+d3);
            Log.v(TAG, "D4="+d4);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    m_statusChecker.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_statusChecker);
}
```

i am stuck with this issue and can't able to find the reason why this happens. please give me some idea how do i fix this issue?

Any idea and help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what's at line 272 in MainActivity??

Comment: `MainActivity.java:272` where error occurs: NPE

Comment: At line `MainActivity.java:272` in `updateStatus()` method it causing null point exception

Comment: @Vino but why in emulator its working ?

Comment: Check Internet Connection in device .

Comment: internet connection is okay @AndroidLearner

Comment: catch Exception at last to avoid ForceClose if it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your logic. Why do you call openConnection from dedicated thread and then working with sockets from UI thread?

I think that on emulator you got lucky and openConnection finishes before you call updateStatus from startRepeatingTask. That is why it works. On the real device you weren't so lucky. Check with debugger that o and i are not null.

Also you share several data objects between threads without proper synchronization. This can give you very tricky bugs )

Comment: Thanks for answer,which objects are not synchronized properly ? it will give me some hint to make my code perfect

Comment: i, for example. First you have InputStream i = null; which is set on UI thread. Later you call openConnection from other thread which sets i = s.getInputStream(). An then you read i from UI thread in updateStatus function. There is no guarantee that UI thread will read i value you set before in other thread.

Comment: i got your point, so what will be the best way to implement this example which you have mentioned ?

Comment: I dont have exact piece of code for you. Take a look at these tutorials [1](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ru/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html), [2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/) and others. And find a best implementation way for your case.

Comment: Thanks, by the way your answer solved my issue of NPE, but i am getting ANR(Application not responding) messages when i am reading/writing on sockets too frequently.

Comment: You use m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker,1000). So m_statusChecker will be ecxecuted on UI thread. And I thinks this line i.read(data1, 0, 1024) blocks UI thread (This method blocks until input data is available).

Comment: ohhh i see,so how do i make this process even faster ? sorry for asking this type of question :(